# edit text not editable after using requestFocus on Gingerbread and below?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have a edit text and i set the following

```
editText.requestFocus()
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(ediText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

It works perfectly fine in ICS and JellyBean but in Gingerbread/Froyo etc the edit text is not editable(whatever user inputs does not show in the edit text) . I have no clue for this wierd behaviour . Any idea to getaround this ?

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Only change getActivity() to getApplicationContext() then i think it will be worked in Gingerbread to ics.

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
    et.requestFocus();
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(et, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```